# Paged list and CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I need to implement paged list, that uses `Loader` to get `Cursor` from `ContentProvider`. I have footer and when user clicks it - I need to add next records to list.

How can I refresh data in the list, using `Loader`? Or what should I do here?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should read [this article about Loaders in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) first, to get a better understanding of how `Loaders` can be used in Android. You can even find `LoaderCursor` example with source codes under Android ApiDemos section in this article.